# call onDestroy after ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE automatically

Tags: android

```
public abstract class Write_MyArticle extends AppCompatActivity{


public Button btn_plus, btn_post, btn_delete;
public EditText edit_title, edit_contents;
public Uri imageUri;
public String absolutePath =null;
public ImageView image;
public RelativeLayout layout;
public Context mContext;
public Activity activity;
public Bitmap imageBitmap;

public final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 900;


public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("message", " passing onDestroy");
    if(imageBitmap != null && imageUri != null){
        Log.d("message", "delete picture in gallery ");
        getContentResolver().delete(imageUri, null,null);
    }
    imageBitmap = null;
    imageUri = null;
}

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
    mContext = this;
    activity = this;
  //  call_camera();
}

public void call_camera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    Log.d("message", "took picture ");

    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA){
        //선택한 사진의 uri
        imageUri = data.getData();

        Log.d("message", "URI : "+imageUri);
        // 선택한 사진의 절대경로 구하는 것
        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        absolutePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));


        Log.d("message", "absolute path of the picture : "+absolutePath);

        imageBitmap = CameraUtil.resizeBitmap(absolutePath);
        imageBitmap = CameraUtil.fixOrientation(imageBitmap, absolutePath);

        Log.d("메시지", "path : "+imageUri.getPath());
        Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(image);
        btn_plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public abstract void init();
```

}

below is an Activity that extends the class above

```
public class Activity_MyDiary extends Write_MyArticle implements View.OnClickListener{

private final int DIARY_TYPE = 1;
private String  title, comments;



public void init(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed_mydiary);
    activity = this;
    mContext = this;
    btn_plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_feed_myDiary_plus);
    btn_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_post = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_feed_myDiary_post);
    btn_post.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_feed_myDiary_delete);
    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    edit_title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_feed_myDiary_title);
    edit_contents = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_feed_myDiary_contents);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_feed_myDiary_captured);
    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_feed_myDiary_image);

}


public void onClick(View v){

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.btn_feed_myDiary_plus:
            call_camera();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_feed_myDiary_post:


            if(absolutePath == null){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "사진이 없습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(edit_title.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "제목을 작성해주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(edit_contents.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "내용을 입력해 주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            title = edit_title.getText().toString();
            comments = edit_contents.getText().toString();

            DB_SendPicture db_sendPicture = new DB_SendPicture(this, this);
            db_sendPicture.setOnResultPicture(sendPictureListener);
            db_sendPicture.execute(imageBitmap);


            break;

        case R.id.btn_feed_myDiary_delete:
            if(imageUri == null){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "사진이 없습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            getContentResolver().delete(imageUri, null,null);
            call_camera();
            break;
    }


}
```

My app has a function that calls camera and captures an image. 
When I click a button in Class number 2, It calls the method call_camera() in ancestor class (upper one)
As you can see, call_camera() method uses ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE and pass the result to onActivityResult()

I have 2 phones to test my app (galaxy S4 and galaxy J3)
Everything works fine on galaxy J3. 
But... when I tried thid code with galaxy S4, 
the phone calls onDestroy() in class Number 1  write after I save the picture.

I think there's no reason to call onDestroy(), because the activity is still on the screen.

Moreover, if I call call_camera() in on create (not from clicking a button)
It works fine on galaxy S4 too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While capturing image camera causes orientation change that time your activity gets destroyed.

This similar issue I got while working in it while working with it.
so, to stop orientation I used below code.

Add these in your menifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".CameraActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    >
</activity>
```

Hope these help you.